# how to compare given date (string) is current date to last 8 date or not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, python-2.7, python-requests

I have an one date in a string. How can I figure out this date REFRESH =  ("2021-11-25 00:27:23") to current date from last 8 days

```py
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
REFRESH =  ("2021-11-25 00:27:23")
today = datetime.now()
n_days_ago = today - timedelta(days=7)
print(today, n_days_ago)
```

I am stuck here.

I need data like if refresh date is true from current date from last 8 days.
"Pass"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your intention is to print current date and days passed from REFRESH I think this one will work

```
refresh_as_datetime=datetime.strptime(REFRESH,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
delta = datetime.now()-refresh_as_datetime
if (delta.days>=8):
    print("not matching") # Refresh date is older than 8 days
else:
    print("it's matching") #  Refresh date is newer than 8 days
```

Comment: No my intention is not to print current date  given date(refresh)  is comes under from now to within last 8days or not. If  given date is matching to the last 8days from not i need to print like "it's matching" if not " not matching " buddy.  thanks for the quick replay

Comment: I have edited my answer accorting to your information.

Comment: Thanks buddy this one is working as expected

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert string to `datetime` object in order to compare, useful function for that is `strptime()` which takes 2 params: string and date format of the string.

Next use `date()` function to get just the date without time, since you want to compare the dates.

Example:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

REFRESH = "2021-11-24 00:27:23"
today = datetime.today()
n_days_ago = today - timedelta(days=7)
if n_days_ago.date() == datetime.strptime(REFRESH, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").date():
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

Comment: Thanks buddy This one also really useful

Comment: @AjithMsM You're welcome. I wasn't sure what you exactly want from the question, to compare them exactly or `>`/`<` but the logic is the same.